# How to not iterate the whole page in Lift

Tags: lift

How can I bind some variables in Lift, so that I can use them outside the "iterating" part of the template.

This is very confusing to me, so I'll pose the question with the help of an example.

Let say I have some snippet method that can provide a list of users, and a total count of these users:

```
def users(in: NodeSeq) :NodeSeq={
   val (entries:List[User], total:Int) = // read entries and total from somewhere
                                         // expensive operation

   entries.flatMap(user => Helpers.bind("patient", in,
  "userID" -> user.userID,
  "userName" -> user.userName))
```

now I want to use it within the template:

```
...
<lift:Search.users> 
 <tr>
  <td><user:userID/></td>
  <td><user:userName/></td>
</tr>
</lift:Search.users>
...
```

However, I also want to output the **total** count of users - but somewhere else on the page:

```
<b>Total users: <user:total></b>   <--- ?????
...
<lift:Search.users> 
 <tr>
  <td><user:userID/></td>
  <td><user:userName/></td>
</tr>
</lift:Search.users>
...
```

as you can imagine this does not work, because it is outside the **Search** snippet tag. Furthermore - if I try to *bind* the total to *users* - it unbinds all my previous binds for the user!

I tried putting the lift tags around the whole document, but that just makes the whole page repeat itself!!

```
<body>
<lift:Search.users>    <---- clones the whole page!


<b>Total users: <user:total></b>
<table>
...

 <tr>
  <td><user:userID/></td>
  <td><user:userName/></td>
</tr>
</table>

</lift:Search.users>
</body>
```

I am new to Lift - so I must be missing something really obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say whether it is optimal or even working solution but you can try using RequestVar: http://simply.liftweb.net/index-4.4.html#toc-Section-4.4 .
You can calculate list and count of users and save the data into RequestVar which will be available in another snippet in current request.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing to do would be to use a separate snippet method for the total, with its own bind definition to separate it from the iterating bind. But I'm a bit new to this, so there may be an easier way.

You may also want to look into the newer designer-friendly style for defining your snippets. I don't think it will make this much easier, but it is probably preferable overall. This approach is outlined in Simply Lift here: http://simply.liftweb.net/index-3.4.html#toc-Section-3.4

Comment: See the problem with this is that I will need to make another request just to get the __total__.

Comment: No, I don't think you do. I just meant what @kevin.mansel suggested, but he actually coded it out :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would just read the user count variable into a different function, and output from there....

```
//Scala Code

private val users = List("kevin", "drozzy", "kyle")

def userList(html : NodeSeq) : NodeSeq = {
users.flatMap(user => bind("user", html, "name" -> user))
}

def userCount = "#count *" #> {users.length}

//HTML Code

<b>Total users: 
    <lift:SearchUsers.userCount>
        <div id="count"/>
    </lift:SearchUsers.userCount>
</b>

<table>
    <lift:SearchUsers.userList>
    <tr>
        <td><user:name/></td>
    </tr>
    </lift:SearchUsers.userList>
</table>
```

Hope that makes sense?

Comment: But I am only building up the "users" in the users() method - I parsed them from the JSON data. Hm... Are you saying that I should store users in a class variable..? I gotta think about this.

Comment: If your entries is a list, then just use the length.  You could just make an empty list, then populate it within your method, you would still have access to the list when you do a render on the page, just make sure you populate it before you run your view population functions.

Comment: Let's say total is not a length of the list - it is the total number of items in the database.